# How to get SVN to ignore a particular directory included in my svn:ignore file?

Tags: svn, svnignore

I’m using Mac 10.9.5 with SVN on the command line.  From within my src/main/webapp/WEB-INF directory, I execute

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

in which the file has two lines …

```
classes
 lib
```

However, when I run “svn status”, it reports “?” for all the JAR files in my lib folder, for example below are some of the files it reports …

```
?       lib/xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar
?       lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
?       lib/xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar
?       lib/xom-1.2.5.jar
```

I know none of these files is under version control because when I run “svn del” on the lib directory, I get this …

```
Daves-MacBook-Pro:WEB-INF davea$ svn del lib
svn: E200005: Use --force to override this restriction (local modifications may be lost)
svn: E200005: '/Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/sbadmin/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/antisamy-1.5.3.jar' is not under version control
```

Does anyone know how to get SVN to ignore files in my lib directory, or barring that, have it ignore my entire lib directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea.  Make sure there are no spaces in front of "lib" in the ignore list.  Also, after saving the edit, you can do an `svn up .` to pull the latest and force it to refresh the status list.

If you're trying to ignore **classes/lib** then do an `svn propedit svn:ignore classes` and set it to "lib".

Comment: Cool.  I don't know why, but I have to do that every once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore contents of `classes/lib` directory, then set `svn:ignore` property on `classes` to `lib`.

For example, use `svn propset` command like this: `svn propset svn:ignore classes lib`. As far as I recall, `svn propedit` won't work unless you specify default text editor in Subversion's runtime configuration area.

You should also be able to set `svn:ignore` property on `lib` to `*` and it will leave the directory itself versioned, but not items under it. However, I guess that the first approach is better.

[Remember to read SVNBook because this is RTFM topic](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html), actually:

> When found on a versioned directory, the svn:ignore property is
>   expected to contain a list of newline-delimited file patterns that
>   Subversion should use to determine ignorable objects in that same
>   directory.